# Use the settings API to Redirect to correct options page after save in Wordpress

Tags: redirect, wordpress

I'm trying to create a new admin page in wordpress for some settings. Ideally, I'd like it to be a top-level menu page, but I'd settle for it being a sub-menu under settings. I've followed all the docs, and I have a page that shows up, and the settings are saved. However, I can't get Wordpress to redirect back to the correct page after hitting save.

I finally simply copied and pasted the code from the Codex into my functions.php: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

And I still have the same problem.

The first example redirects to admin.php, which causes a plain white screen while the second example redirects to the main settings page instead of the custom settings sub-page.

Surely there has to be a way to tell Wordpress to redirect to your custom page after saving.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triggering factor for this might be the form's `action` attribute.

Depending on how you save your settings, you probably want to have your action point to `options.php` most of the time.

Other than that, `settings_field()` is also important in your form. It'll add several hidden input fields to identify the form.

Using [*this code*](https://gist.github.com/josephting/6c0ba79bbdb0d98faf69) as an example works perfectly for me at least on WP 3.9.

Comment: I was pointing towards options and using settings_field(). I just tried that code and updated to 3.9. I'm still not getting the correct redirect. Instead of `options-general.php?page=mysettings` It redirects to `options-general.php?settings-updated=true`. Without that page parameter, the correct settings page doesn't appear. Could it be some sort of server config?

Comment: The easy way to check if that's the case is to add another settings page from scratch and test this out using the example code I posted in the answer. See if everything save correctly and redirected to the correct page. If it does not, could be server config or conflict caused by other plugins.

Comment: It looks like it's some kind of configuration on my development machine. Uploading to staging and the example code worked fine. Marking this as correct, as the action and settings_fields() function are technically required. Thanks!

Comment: The `settings_field()` pointed me in the right direction, but I want to add to this answer by saying: make sure the `settings_field() function is **inside** the ```<form>``` tag! I was trying to optimize a bit and had it outside the form which did not work.